# Jenkins CI/CD process to build docker image and more based on git commit ID

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, devops

I have this following requirement.

1.user will give the GIT commit ID using the Jenkins parameterized option.

2.Pull the code from the Git lab using that git commit ID and only data(code) committed up to that particular commit, but code which committed after that shouldn't be included.

3.Build the docker image using the code pulled from the GIT.

4.push the image to docker repository.

5. Deploy the same docker image in a particular server.

I have pipeline code to do all the above process, but i need help to pass the git commit id to script using the jenkins parameterized build. and pull the code not to clone.

Please help/suggest me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

here is the code

```
node{

stage('SCM Checkout'){

ppname:2.0.0 .'
}
git credentialsId: '', url: 'http://some.com/'

}

stage('Build Docker Image'){
..............
```

Comment: please add what you already did/try to achieve this

Comment: Actually I'm stuck at second step, I'm not able to pull the data from git using the commit ID

Comment: then you can use `git checkout specific-commit-id` command for that

Comment: Second step -> `git clone ssh/http-url ; cd project-folder ;  git reset --hard commit-id`

Comment: Thanks Amit and smilyface,please help  with next steps also

Comment: Amit and smileyface i have added code to my question, please check

Comment: hmm. I am asking the same question @AmitNanaware asked. What have you tried so far to achieve it ? Please ask help on an issue not on a feature. Mean time please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask